# Is it possible to play YouTube playlists in reverse order?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

As most YouTube playlists seem to be updated at their start, it would be quite useful to play those playlists, on a PC or in the Android Go app, in reverse order. I would also be interested in the reason why playlists are updated like this, as there has to be a reason for it!

Answer (score 15):

I ran into a site that seems to do exactly what you asked for:
https://playlist.tools/

It allows reverse playlist playback and doesn't need you to install any browser extensions

Comment: Thanks so much for this!

Answer (score 5):

You can play it in date order from oldest published to newest using this site:
http://www.playbackloop.com/

But I am still looking for a way to simply reverse order

Comment: I searched for hours nothing else works, this is the only working solution.

Comment: It doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 2):

**This guide is for chrome users.**

I am using this solution right now so I can confirm that it works.

---

**Step one:** Download the "Reverse Youtube Playlist" chrome add-on. (The add-on was last updated in 2014, but if you follow these steps it will still work)

**Step two:** Go to the youtube playlist that you want to reverse and add this to the end of the URL: &disable_polymer=true.

So your complete URL should look something like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1nd8WPZO_c&list=PL34C1F26D03F5F9B8&index=94&disable_polymer=true

**Step three:** The playlist bar should now look slightly different. You will also notice that there is an extra button on the playlist bar with a down and up arrow. This is the button to reverse the playlist using the add-on you downloaded earlier.

---

Clicking this button should reverse the current order of the playlist. The reason you need to add the text to the URL is because the add-on only works if you are using the old version of youtube.

If youtube decides to take away the old version this solution might stop working.

That is the solution. Enjoy

Comment: Thanks, this work like a charm.

Comment: No longer works for me. The visual order is reversed, but not playback.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with a Chrome extension called Improved YouTube!. It's open source and supported on GitHub. Some settings can be somewhat buggy at times but overall it is wonderful. Install it [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/improve-youtube-open-sour/bnomihfieiccainjcjblhegjgglakjdd).

Then go to Improved YouTube! Settings → playlist → enable reverse.

Comment: not works https://github.com/ImprovedTube/YouTube/issues/590

Comment: Old extension doesn't work, but Beta one works (requires enabling reversing in extension settings): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/improvedtube-testing/lodjfjlkodalimdjgncejhkadjhacgki

Comment: Now, at enable the option, you get a button with two arrows (one up one down) in the playlist panel. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ive figured it out when you are on your playlist add &disable_polymer=true. to the end of your url then install the extensions "reverse youtube playlist" and "Improve Youtube! (Open-source for youtube)" then pin and click on the "Improve youtube" extension then click on playlist then click "reverse" and then there will be a black "up and down" button on the youtube playlist you want to reverse and it will reverse